# apply proc means to quickly calculate multiple observations?

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with varying observations per ID, and these participants are also in different treatment status (Group). I wonder if I can use proc means to quickly calculate the number of participants and visits to clinic per group status by using proc means? Ideally, I can use proc means sum function quickly capture those with 0 and 1 based on group status and gain the total number? However, I got stuck in how to proceed.

```
ID Visit Group 
1  1     0
1  2     0
2  1     1
2  2     1
2  3     1
3  1     0
4  1     1
4  2     1
5  1     0
5  2     0
6  1     1
6  2     1
6  3     1
6  4     1
```

Specifically, I am interested in 1) the total number of participants in each group status. In this case we can 3 participants (ID:1,3,and 5)in the control group (0) and another 3 participants (ID:2,4,and 6) in the treatment group (1).
2) the total number of visits per group status. In this case, the total visits in the control group (0) will be 5 (2+1+2=5) and the total visits in the treatment group (1) will be 9 (3+2+4=9).
I wonder if proc means procedure can help quickly calculate such values? Thanks.

Comment: Please show the result you want for that given input.

Comment: I want to see the sum of total 0s and 1s (based on group status) to see how many participants are in different groups. However, given each participant has varying numbers of visits shown on each row, I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: proc means data=one noprint;
by Group;
var Visit Group;
output out=onenew (drop=_TYPE_ _FREQ_) sum = /autoname;
run;     For example, this one gave a total visit number as the total Group number, but these numbers are calculated multiple times should one ID has multiple visits (in this case, their group status 1 will also be added multiple times).

Comment: What numbers do you want for the actual example data you showed?

Comment: There is no first() or last() function.  Your data step is just making permanent variables to save the temporary FIRST.ID and LAST.ID flags.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `proc means` to get counts.

```
data have;
  input ID$ Visit Group;
  cards;
1 1 0
1 2 0
2 1 1
2 2 1
2 3 1
3 1 0
4 1 1
4 2 1
5 1 0
5 2 0
;
run;

proc means data=have n;
  class group id;
  var visit;
  types group id group*id;
run;
```

If you want the sum of `visit`, add "sum" behind `proc means data=have n` and `;`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like GROUP is assigned at the ID level and not the ID/VISIT level.  In that case if you want to count the number of ID's in each group you need to first get down to one observation per ID.

```
proc sort data=have nodupkey out=unique_ids ;
  by id;
run;
```

Now you can count how many ID's are in each group.  The normal way is to use PROC FREQ.

```
proc freq data=unique_ids;
  tables group;
run;
```

But you can count with PROC MEANS/SUMMARY also.

```
proc summary data=unique_ids nway;
  class group;
  output out=counts N=N_ids ;
run;
proc print data=counts;
  var group n_ids;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you! It's helpful. I realized in this case, the duplicates of visits are eliminated with the nodupkey. I wonder how these will generate the total number of visits per group given different participants have varying visits (1-5).

Comment: Total visits can be counted directly from the original data. (unless there are multiple observations per subject_id/visit).  Update the question to show the counts you actually want to produce (with the expected results for the example input data you provided).

Comment: Thank you! I hope the updated version helps.

Comment: So use MEANS twice.  Once to summarize by ID*group. Then summarize the resulting dataset by GROUP. `proc  summary nway; class group id ; output out=step1; run; proc summary data=step1; by group; var _freq_; output out=want n=n_subject sum=n_visits; run;`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried to use another codes proc sort data=one;
by ID Group;
run;
proc means data=one;
by Group;
output out=oneout n=n_total;
run;
proc print data=oneout;
var Group n_total;
run;     It seems that I can get the same total visits from this but I am unable to get the number of participants per group, I wonder if I can add some functions in the proc means to get them?

Answer (score 0):

MEANS doesn't do a distinct count easily so SQL may be a simpler to understand option here.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select group, count(*) as num_visits, count(distinct ID) as num_participants
from have
group by group
order by 1;
quit;
```